# Service not running as intending

Tags: windows, service

I have a C# windows service called serviceconnect. Built it from visual studio. I am using installutil.exe serviceconnect.exe

[image: installed successfully]

It does not appear in services tab, to use in the command promt "net start serviceconnect" or "net start serviceconnect.exe" , it says "service name is invalid".

What am i missing?

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: Code is not important here.